# Where is the YAML file containing the user permissions stored?

Tags: 8

Which directory contains the YAML file where user permissions per role are stored? I looked in the core.entity.yml and do not know where else to look.

Comment: 1. `drush cex`. 2. Change a permission via UI. 3. `drush cex` again, then check what gets printed in the terminal and you will know.

Answer (score 4):

They are stored in the `user.role.ROLE_NAME.yml` files with the rest of configuration exports.

Comment: what directory is that in ?  can't seem to find it.

Comment: The same as all the other configuration files that get exported? I don't know what you mean.

Comment: right I don't know what directory to look in .  I tried /config and I do not see them there. I also looked in /docroot/core/config not there either

Comment: Where are you exporting them to? Thats where you need to look.

Comment: @Kevin she probably means “where is the active config stored”, thinking that’s also in yml files. Diana, that information is in the database until you export it. Specifically in the `config` table, though you’ll probably also find it in `config_snapshot` and `cache_config`

Comment: no I mean where is the .yml file stored.  what directory.

Comment: There is no yml file until you create one. You’re asking the wrong question

Comment: I don't know where they are exported too since I did not set it up.  what is the default export directory?

Comment: When you run the export process I think it’ll tell you where it’s exporting to. If you haven’t run that process, they may not exist yet. Think the default is /config

Comment: For anyone else that stumbles on this conversation, the config is likely stored in the config/sync if you have config sync set up directory.